# Watson Conversation is not taking true conditions

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, php-curl, watson

I have my Watson Conversation which is working fine on bluemix. When I'm integrating it onto my website (using php curl, JS) , Watson isn't taking the "true conditions" or the "jump to" alternatives. It is only responding to my intents and entities. On Bluemix, it works fine. Where is the mistake? 
[The Bluemix conversation node snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlhBi.jpg)

Comment: Watson Conversation is REST based andis agnostic to from where u call it. Pls post more info on how u actually call it from your browser

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this is that you are not setting the context object when making the call. So conversation thinks you are asking a new question.

Pass back the context object you receive and it should continue on where you left off.